# How to flag any missing documents in a document sets

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, document

I was wondering if there is a method to flag out missing documents in a document set.
For example, document set 1 has 5 require document and 2 of the documents are missing. Is there a method to flag or highlight the set to indicate the missing documents?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new Yes/No column "IsMissing" in the document library to flag the documents are missing or not.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I would have to manually check the document sets for any missing documents. Is there any method to automate it?

Comment: You can set the value for this field using workflow automate.